# Is it possible to create Elasticsearch Index from Kibana defined pipeline?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I installed [Dockerized ELS Stack](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk) and created a logstash index via bash - and that works properly.

Is it possible to do the same in Kibana?

I created a new pipeline (Logstash > Pipelines > Create Pipeline button), placing the same pipeline.conf content (the one I used for the manual procedure) in the 'Pipeline' textbox. After pressing 'Create and deploy' button I can't figure out if something has happened or not (no visual feedback).
From Elasticsearch > Index Management I was expecting to see enlisted my new index but that's not the case. Do I have to reboot something?
I'm completely new to the ELK stack so please bear with me.

Comment: This is a paid feature, you need a subscription, your are probably using it in the trial mode, if you still want to try the feature you will need to edit the `logstash.yml` file that your container is using and add [these configs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuring-centralized-pipelines.html#configuring-centralized-pipelines).

Comment: Hi @leandrojmp , I guess you're right and this answers my question. If you add this as an answer instead of a comment I'll mark it as solved. Thanks